# Lua file output: what is -1.#IO?

Tags: file, lua, numbers, output

I'm printing numbers into a file with Lua, and on occasion instead of a number, -1.#IO will be displayed. What does it mean?

The offending code is in the following gist.

https://gist.github.com/Nelarius/6247636

And the offending number is at the very bottom: meanPrice. The value contained is stored in the Commodity table, and the Commodity table later on logs the value into a file.

Comment: I'll say that it's a NaN value (a special value of floating points). Perhaps even the negative NaN (but it doesn't change anything... a NaN is a NaN). To make it clear: `0.0 / 0.0`

Comment: @xanatos I agree with your suggestion but have to disagree that "a NaN is a NaN." There are signaling NaN and quiet NaNs. Quiet NaNs propagate nicely through computations. Signaling NaNs' behaviour depends on the system.

Comment: Could you add the code that's doing the writing please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is, as the commentors say, an invalid number. It should only appear like this on Windows.

See the link below.

Note, the link refers to (-)1.#IND for NaNs and (-)1.#INF for infinity which I get too. 
I would be interested in what you're doing to generate the #IO.

[IEEE Floating point exceptions](http://www.johndcook.com/IEEE_exceptions_in_cpp.html)

Comment: Thank you for your link. I used the debugging info provided and printed my offending number, and it seems that my 1.#IO is actually an indeterminate number. So somewhere I am performing an illegal operation.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows, the floating point number has output of `1.#INF` for positive infinity and `-1.#INF` for negative infinity. The floating point indeterminate number is `-1.#IND`. But there's no similar representation of `-1.#IO`.

The most probable reason is, you are outputting numbers with a fixed 3 digits of fraction part. And for 3 digits after the decimal point `.`, `.#INF` or `.#IND` get rounded up to `.#IO`.

```
print(-1/0)
print(0/0)
print((string.format("%.3f", -1/0)))
print((string.format("%.3f", 0/0)))
```

On windows, the output is:

```
-1.#INF
-1.#IND
-1.#IO
-1.#IO
```